# Is $E(\frac 1X|X>1)=E(\frac {1}{X+1}) $ where X follows binomial distribution?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

Please help with this question.
 I tried to directly find  $E(\frac 1X), X \sim bin(n,p)$.

Comment: What was the result when you tried to find it directly? Where did you get stuck? Please show your work.

Comment: I couldn't find E(1/X) because the summation starts with zero, so it didn't make sense, i.e. \sum_{k=0}^{k=n}1/k*pmf. However, in my problem statement X is the number of survivors, and for the problem to work I know there must be at least one survivor who can take a payment. Therefore, I added that condition.I know the value for E(1/1+X).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they are not equal.

---

Write

\begin{align}
E[1/X\mid X>1]=\sum_{k=2}^n \frac1{k}\cdot P(X=k\mid X>1) =\sum_{k=2}^n \frac1{k}\cdot \frac{P(X=k)}{P(X>1)}
\end{align}
The $P(X>1)$ is just a constant which we can factor out. When you do, what is left is
$$
E[1/X\mid X>1]=\frac1{P(X>1)}\sum_{k=2}^n \frac1k\binom{n}kp^k(1-p)^{n-k}
$$
For simplicity, let $x=\frac{p}{1-p}$. Then we can write this as
$$
E[1/X\mid X>1]=\frac{(1-p)^n}{P(X>1)}\sum_{k=2}^n \frac1k\binom{n}kx^k\tag1
$$
That last summation kind of looks like the binomial theorem, $(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}k x^k$. We can use this similarity to find a closed form for that sum. Rearrange the binomial theorem like this (using a different variable, $t$):
$$
\frac{(1+t)^n-1-nt}{t}=\sum_{k=2}^n\binom{n}k t^{k-1}
$$
Then, integrate both sides from $0$ to $x$ in $t$.
$$
\int_0^x \frac{(1+t)^n-1-nt}t\,dt = \sum_{k=2}^n\binom{n}k \frac1k x^{k}\tag2
$$
Notice how integration causes the $1/k$ to appear. As long as you can carry out the integration in $(2)$, then you can plug that formula in to $(1)$ to get the answer.